# C# socket download file from REST API

Tags: c#, sockets, http, get

I'm talking to a custom API, that will give me a file, if I send a GET request, with a body.  And yes, I'm fully aware of how horrible that is, so please don't remind me.

I'm using Sockets to send the requests, and normally these GET requests return JSON data, which I can read just fine.  However, I now need to download a file, and the socket keeps on closing.  To be specific, I keep on getting this exception:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

If I use curl to make the request, I get the file:

```
curl -d '{"thing" : "blah"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/0.1/test/download  > test.zip
```

If I use fiddler, I get the file returned.

But C# sockets keep on throwing that exception.  I don't have any code to show, as I really don't know the best way to handle the data transfer.  But I've tried no end of loops, and nothing seems to be working.  If anyone could provide some guidance on how to do this, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks